# Why does .NET Core Razor pages validate controls which are not set as required?

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages, data-annotations

I'm having an issue where I have a property in my page model which is from a domain class and there are several fields which I don't want validated.  Those which need validation I've decorated with [Required] but when I leave the fields which are not required empty, the ModelState is showing those as being invalid.

I'm hoping someone can maybe tell me why this is happening and how to stop it.

This is part of the code from my PageModel and the property which I'm having the issue with is Application

```
public class RecordApplicationModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Sponsor Sponsor1 { get; set; } = new Sponsor();
    [BindProperty]
    public Sponsor Sponsor2 { get; set; } = new Sponsor();
    [BindProperty]
    public Application Application { get; set; } = new Application();
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; } = new List<Member>();
    public List<SelectListItem> MemberList { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

This is the cshtml file

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table style=width:40%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" value="@Model.Application.FirstName" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.LastName" type="text" name="LastName" value="@Model.Application.LastName" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.Address" type="text" name="Address" value="@Model.Application.Address" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.City" type="text" name="City" value="@Model.Application.City" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.City" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Province</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.Province" type="text" name="Province" value="@Model.Application.Province" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.Province" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Postal Code</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.PostalCode" type="text" name="PostalCode" value="@Model.Application.PostalCode" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.PostalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.Phone" type="text" name="Phone" value="@Model.Application.Phone" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Alternate Phone</td>
                        <td><input asp-for="Application.AlternatePhone" type="text" name="AlternativePhone" value="@Model.Application.AlternatePhone" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="Application.Email" type="text" name="Email" value="@Model.Application.Email" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Application.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date Of Birth</td>
                            <td>
                                <input asp-for="Application.DateOfBirth" type="date" name="DateOfBirth" value="@Model.Application.DateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Application.DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Occupation</td>
                        <td><input asp-for="Application.Occupation" type="text" name="Occupation" value="@Model.Application.Occupation" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

And this is my domain class

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Province is required")]
    public string Province { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal Code is required")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
    public string Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AlternatePhone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth is required")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CompanyPostalCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string CompanyPhone { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusDesc { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    public MemberType MemberType { get; set; } = new MemberType();

    public List<Sponsor> Sponsors { get; set; } = new List<Sponsor>();
}
```

Comment: I think the empty might be translating as null.  So if you have "string" it can't be null.  Whereas "string?" type would be ok.  Try adding [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)] to model.

Comment: Adding the DisplayFormat annotation did the trick, thanks so much!!